# What is this symbol above the X?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Not sure what it is, $X$ is a set that contains ${2, 5, 6}$.

This is all the text says.

"Let $U =\{1, 2, 3,\dots, 10\}$ be the universal set and consider the following subsets of $U$;$X = \{2, 5, 6\}$ and $Y = \{5,9\}$.

[image: X is a set containing {2, 5, 6}]

Comment: I think it could be its complementary

Comment: It **must** be defined earlier in your text; without this context, we can only guess (it could be complement, it could be closure, etc.)

Comment: It could be the closure of X.

Comment: I agree with Aaron Maroja. There is no context to talk about complementary.

Comment: It is the compelment of $x$ in $U$, i.e. $U - X = \{ 1,2,3,…,10 \} - \{ 2,5,6 \} = \{ 1,3,4,7,8,9,10 \}$.

Answer (score 0):

The two most common interpretations of that particular symbol in the context of set theoretic notation is for the complement of a set or the closure of a set.  However, we can not provide a definitive answer without more context and your best bet is ensuring it was not previously defined in your text or, as MJD says in the comment below, is not defined in a glossary of some sort within the text.

Comment: Or the book may have a "glossary of symbols" at the back somewhere.

Comment: I agreed with MJD - another thing to check.